# Using the dedicated gpu on laptop for specified with Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, asus-laptop, manjaro

I have a laptop that have a dedicated gpu and integrated gpu. I'm wondering how can I force the use of the dedicated gpu for specified app?

I looked at this [old thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/753947) however there's no option for the GPU to use.

I opened nvidia x server setting. There was option to set profile by application to set which app to use. I didn't understood how to specify the use of a certain GPU for a specific app(where can I select the GPU to use?).

I use the kde variant of manjaro. My laptop is a Asus tuf fx504gd. My GPU is a nvidia gtx 1050 with 2gb of vram.

Comment: It can be somewhat automatic these days. See https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/6ftq10/the_ultimate_guide_to_setting_up_nvidia_optimus/

Comment: @xenoid I used nvidia xrun as I wanted performence however minecraft still do not run off the dedicated gpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the application called [optimus manager](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager#important--gnome-and-gdm-users). The application allow you to change the current used GPU for optimus laptop. If you use manjaro with the KDE like I do you have to edit the file `etc/sddm.conf`  and simply put a # before the line starting with DisplayCommand the one starting with DisplayStopCommand.

You should also know that you might also run into into problem if you use the gnome variant of manjaro or any distro with gnoem. The instruction for solving the problem are described [here](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager#important--gnome-and-gdm-users)

I recommend to anyone using optimus-manager to use the qt version as it will have a graphical interface.

Sources :

- https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager/blob/master/README.md
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME

Comment: Is this a typo? __DisplayCommandand__

Comment: @vssher yes, and I corrected the error